# MySQL Order By Number of Matches

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order a MySQL select statement by the **total number of matches in a row**. For example, if the table looks like ...

```
id | dessert | choice
---------------------
1  | pie     | apple pie, chocolate pie 
2  | cake    | chocolate cake, lemon cake, white chocolate cake, triple chocolate cake
3  | donut   | frosted donut, chocolate donut, chocolate cream donut
```

... and if someone searches for `chocolate`, the results ought to be ordered:

```
dessert | matches
-----------------
cake    | 3
donut   | 2
pie     | 1
```

However, I'm struggling to make the query ordered like this. I've looked at other examples here, but they seem overly complicated for what I guessed would be a fairly simple thing.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this? I'm new to MySQL, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious question.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

P.S. I'm not able to use `fulltext` on this table, hence I can't order the results by relevancy.

Comment: Is table `MyISAM` or `InnoDB`? In a `MyISAM` table you can use some `FULLTEXT` capabilities even without creating a `FULLTEXT` index.

Comment: is it possible for you to change your tables?  with the comma separated list in your Choice field you are breaking the rules of normalization...awm's table structure should be what you go with if you can change it....

Comment: Thanks guys. Quassnoi, it's MyISAM. I didn't know some of the capabilities are still available without a `FULLTEXT` index, so thanks for the tip. Leslie, yes, I went with this solution in the end. The original data was in CSV format, so I thought one table would be fine. I was wrong :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about dividing your data into two tables - one defining the desserts and one defining the choices?  This would make the queries simpler and faster.

Desserts table:

```
id | dessert
------------
1  | pie
2  | cake
3  | donut
```

Choices table:

```
id | choice
-----------
1  | apple pie
1  | chocolate pie 
2  | chocolate cake
2  | lemon cake
2  | white chocolate cake
2  | triple chocolate cake
3  | frosted donut
3  | chocolate donut
3  | chocolate cream donut
```

Then you could do something like:

```
select `dessert`, count(*) as `matches`
       from `desserts` join `choices` using (`id`)
       where `choice` like '%chocolate%'
       group by `id`
       order by `matches` desc
```

Comment: Thanks awm! I've just finished spliting up the table (in reality there are 100,000 'desserts' and 170,000 'choices'). Anyway, after some quick tests: a) it works perfectly, and b) it's 29-42% faster than the single-table solution. Thanks very much for your clear guidance and example; I've learnt a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Just strip out the matching word and then compare the difference in string lengths

```
SELECT id
     , desert
     , ( LENGTH(choice) - LENGTH(REPLACE(choice,'chocolate','')) )
       / LENGTH('chocolate') AS matches
FROM desert_table
WHERE choice LIKE '%chocolate%'
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Sodved! This is a really clever approach; I wouldn't have thought of using the string lengths to calculate the matches, and it adds relatively little overhead too. In the end I went with the solution above, because of the performance benefit, but if I had to use just one table, then your solution would be perfect. Thanks again; this is really helpful! (P.S. For any others using this with mixed case strings, remember to `LOWER()` the `REPLACE()` values, otherwise you'll get some incorrect '0' matches).